# Why does compressor output 960x540 when frame size is specified "up to 1280x720"?

Tags: video, video-quality, codec, final-cut-pro-x

Is there any way to produce output video at 1280x720 resolution using the "Apple Devices HD (Most Compatible)" setting in Compressor? When I specify a frame size of "up to 1280x720", the output renders at 960x540. This screenshot shows what I'm talking about:

[image]

By contrast, if I specify a frame size of ["up to 1920x1080"](http://monosnap.com/image/QylTioGPGK3LArmNRCFRMgWr0jDA7n) or ["up to 960x540"](http://monosnap.com/image/HXqULC7PFUoxbJyPqeE5eoN8cQPetb), Compressor produces output at the specified resolution. My source video is at 1920x1080 resolution.

Answer (score 3):

The original AppleTV could only playback at 1280x720 at 24fps. Because your video is at 25fps, it has to use a slightly lower resolution. If you either lower the frame rate (probably not an option) or exclude the original AppleTV, it should export at the higher resolution. I believe there's another setting than the "Most Compatible" one which excludes the older AppleTVs.